# SocketException while closing application

Tags: java, websocket, youtube, socketexception, jwebbrowser

I'm making a twitch bot which gets requests via chat and loads a youtube player via JWebBrowser from the requested link, but when i close the application i get a socket exception (Unless i remove the component used to display the JWebBrowser component).
This is the stacktrace:

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.peek(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peek(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readUnshared(Unknown Source)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.OutProcessSocketsMessagingInterface.readMessageFromChannel(OutProcessSocketsMessagingInterface.java:116)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.MessagingInterface$2.run(MessagingInterface.java:392)
```

I have no idea what do in order to solve the issue that is causing this exception to be thrown.
Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to show us your code where the error is occuring (OutProcessSocketsMessagingInterface.java:116).

Comment: I sadly can't provide you with that line as it's from an external library i'm using to access twitch chat (basically it gets link requests from the chat and plays a video on my software), but i don't think there's any problem in it, rather i doubt my programming but i have no idea where to look in my code..

Answer (score 0):

This Exception is your friend. In short, it's the mechanism in which the thread that is blocked on the `read(...)` call gets freed up when the socket is closed.

Comment: Yeah but i'd like to avoid throwing it since when i close the application windows says it has stopped working, it's annoying..

Comment: So don't throw it, eat it. Your comment has nothing to do with the question that you asked

Comment: My question was how to proceed into solving the issue that is causing this exception to be thrown, i'm sorry if i wasn't clear on that.